# Fetch value from Exception

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception, downcast

I am getting a NumberFormatException and i want to fetch the value from the exception itself , which looks like 
[image]

But there is no getter available for the value, can anyone suggest any solution to fetch this value rather than reflection, or even reflection can be fine.

Comment: extend the Exception and add your own value/getter. What do you need it for, actually?

Comment: @Stultuske How should an own Exception help here? Non of the used libraries would know this new exception type.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by getting this value?

Comment: @Stultuske : Thanks for your suggestion,but this exception is thrown by spring itself when it tries to map the request value using jackson

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh : I have to use this value for logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you explicitly check for [TypeMismatchException](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException.html#getValue()), you can retrieve that value simply by calling `getValue()`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException.html#getValue()

Comment: Sorry it was accidentally happened , even i was unaware !!! I accepted it again, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could get value from org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException just use Object getValue(), for example, using following code:

```
...
} catch(Exception exception) {
   if(exception instanceof TypeMismatchException) {
      Object value = ((TypeMismatchException) exp).getValue;
      ... // what you want to do with value
   }
}
```

or just

```
...
} catch(TypeMismatchException exception) {
      Object value = exp.getValue;
      ... // what you want to do with value
}
```

Because [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android/blob/master/spring-android-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException.java) define as

```
package org.springframework.beans;
public class TypeMismatchException extends PropertyAccessException {
...
    /**
     * Return the offending value (may be {@code null})
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
...
}
```